# Compiling Java from Command Line

Tags: java, compilation, windows-console

I'm following this [tutorial on how to build an Android Plugin for Unity](http://randomactsofdev.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-the-android-compass-through-unity-3d/)

I'm currently at the part where the author tells me to do the following in command line:

> 1.> javac CompassActivity.java -classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar
>   -bootclasspath C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\android.jar -d .
>
> 2.> javap -s com.yourcompany.yourgamename.CompassActivity
>
> 3.> jar cvfM ../Compass.jar com/

However when I type the following line:

```
javac CompassActivity.java -classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar
```

I get the following message:

```
javac: invalid flags: (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar
usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

So I've tried retyping the line putting my path of the file in angled brackets, placing a dot in between classpath and the start of my file location, but I keep getting the same issue.

Am I using classpath wrong?

If so, what is the correct way I should be doing it?

I should add that the console does point to the correct folder location. That was the first thing I've checked.

Comment: try putting the path between ""  like "c:\progra..."

Comment: Try enclosing the path with `"`s like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spaces in the path to `classes.jar`, you must enclose it using `"`, or shell will consider it as three distinct parameters (`C:\Program`, `Files` and `(x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar"`):

```
javac CompassActivity.java -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try the command like:

usage: `javac <options> <source files>`

```
javac -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin\classes.jar" CompassActivity.java
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check your System is 32-bit or 64-bit

check it out full steps for Config and run:http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
javac -cp filepath
```

or you also try to set the classpath first by command

```
set classpath="filepath"
```

Then u can try with a command

```
java filepath
```